# javascript, jquery setInetval append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, append

I have code:

```js
<div id='chatbox-list'></div>
<script>
    function Test() {
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/blabla'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                         $('#chatbox-list').append(data);
                    }
                });
                            
            }
            
    setInterval(Test, 2000);
</script>
```

date is:

```js
<div id='test'> </div>
    
    Any HTML

<script>
    function Name(){
       $.ajax()
    .....
       $('#test').append('blabla');
    .....
    }

    setInterval(Name,1000);
</script>
```

After adding HTML and Javascript to the div id='chatbox-list', how to make setInterval(Name,1000) and function Name() run accordingly?
Maybe there is some other solution that allows to perform a dynamically added function after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Test(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  type: 'get',
  success: function(response){
    $('#chatbox-list').append(`<li>${response.title}</li>`);
  }
 });
}

$(function(){
 setInterval(Test,1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="chatbox-list"></ul>
```

here is demo how append data with interval. you can do same with post method. just listen it on success callback and append delivered data to dom